# What's the right way to pass a Fortran zero-length arrays to C?

Tags: c, arrays, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have the following kind of subroutine wrapper to pass a Fortran array to a `ISO_C_BINDING`-bound C function.

```
subroutine mysub( array )
  integer, dimension(:) :: array
  call f_mysub( size(array) , array(1) )
end subroutine
```

The problem is that if the array is of size 0 then `array(1)` is out-of-bounds. What's the right way to handle this situation?

In general I cannot avoid the call, i.e. with a `if( size(array) > 0 )` because the call may be important to register, e.g. it is actually a class method, naturally with different signature than above, and could clear an existing array.

### Example Files

The C routine is `c_mysub.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void c_mysub( size_t* size, int* arr )
{
    printf("size=%d\n",*size);
    for(size_t i=0; i<*size; ++i)
    {
        printf("element %d=%d\n",i,arr[i]);
    }
}
```

The main Fortran file is `mysub.f90`

```
module mysub_I
interface
subroutine f_mysub( size, arr) BIND(C,name="c_mysub")
    use,intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
    integer(C_SIZE_T) :: size
    integer(C_INT) :: arr
end subroutine
end interface
end module

module mysub_M
use mysub_I
contains

subroutine mysub( array )
  use ISO_C_BINDING
  integer, dimension(:) :: array
  call f_mysub( int(size(array),C_SIZE_T) , array(1) )
end subroutine

end module

program main
use mysub_M
integer, allocatable :: x(:)

allocate( x(7) )
x=1

call mysub( x )

deallocate( x )
allocate( x(0) )

call mysub( x )

end
```

Compile the C with `gcc -c c_mysub.c` and the Fortran with `gfortran -fbounds-check c_mysub.o mysub.f90`, which gives the following error when you run the code, balking at the second call with size=0.

```
size=7
0:1
1:1
2:1
3:1
4:1
5:1
6:1
At line 18 of file mysub.f90
Fortran runtime error: Index '1' of dimension 1 of array 'array' above upper bound of 0
```

Compiling with bounds check off behaves as expected.

```
size=7
0:1
1:1
2:1
3:1
4:1
5:1
6:1
size=0
```

Comment: You can temporarily dimension your array to 1 if it is empty.

Comment: ... Or have a dummy array ready for the occasion.

Comment: What is the interface for `c_mysub`?  Why do you wish to pass a scalar array element to it, even when the array may have no elements?

Comment: Just to back up francescalus why are you not just passing the array?

Comment: Normally you should pass just  `array`, not `array(1)`. Hard to say more if you don't show the real code. There is some risk of `array` being non-contiguous and `array(1)` will avoid creating a temporary copy and that could actually be wrong.

Comment: I added more details and renamed the functions.

Comment: I'm sorry I made another modification to show files I am testing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any reason to pass `array(1)` as actual argument. The whole array `array` should be passed.

```
  call f_mysub( size(array) , array )
```

and the interface must be changed to pass an array and not just a scalar

```
  integer(C_INT) :: arr(*)
```

Passing the first element (even to an array argument) could easily cause incorrect behaviour if `array` is not contiguous - which is theoretically possible given it is assumed shape dummy argument (with `(:)`).

If you pass the whole array and size `0` then just make sure no element is actually dereferenced from the pointer in the C procedure (which should already be the case if it is well-written).

Comment: What does the f_mysub look like in that case? The `c_mysub` will have `int[] arr` as argument, right?

Comment: Now I only realized you have a wrong interface, you must indeed correct it.

Comment: The C argument can be array or pointer, it does not matter. `int *array` is fine.

Comment: Is it not the case that an array of zero size is not interoperable with any C array?

Comment: I was just going to check that. It possibly is not. But in practice, whatever address is passed, it should not be dereferenced. Even a null pointer can be passed. One could add an if and pass a `c_null_pointer` instead, but I don't think it is worth it. I just have to check no bad stuff happens on the Fortran side.

Comment: I have tested your suggested change and no errors with -fbounds-check.